# best connected combination to beat AA

Tags: learning

buddy and I debate
does 89 offsuit have a better chance of making a straight than 10 J off?

give us a calculator to prove one way or the other

Comment: Check out the post herb suggested. I explain exactly why 98 has better equity than JT. You can always use propokertools.com as a calculator.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently 56s is statistically the best hand to play against Aces, wouldn't recommend it though.

Comment: Link to source? or show how you came to that conclusion? Thanks.